# XSLT transform to check if a set of nodes has at least one matching value

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

My XML Looks as follows:
XSLT 1

```
<Root>
  <Test>
    1
  </Test>
  <Test>
    2
  </Test>
</Root>
```

My XSLT expression is `<xsl:value-of select="Test">`

This returns 1, as it just selects the first element.

What I want is it to be True if any of the TestElements contains "2" and False if they don't.

How can I accomplish this with a simple XSLT expression?  Assume there can be 1 or many test elements.

Answer (score 0):

use predicate to match text() of the element:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Test[text()=2]" />
```

In a condition:

```
<xsl:if test="Test[text()=2]">
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Better is `Test[. = 2]` as you never know when someone will introduce a comment node to confound you...